# Stack Smashing problem in real time data writing to database

Tags: sql

Have a program that receives burst traffic .Adds to linked list and then processes to writing to database.Seen stack smashing.Then no response of asynchronous message......

Answer (score 0):

Stack smashing definition: http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/sDefinition/0,,sid14_gci913633,00.html

By what you are describing, your linked list is getting more data added to it than it can handle, assuming "Stack smashing" is the problem you know you are experiencing.

The solution is to make sure to code to keep the linked list from getting bigger than its limit.